# Graph not updating on change of value. Using react-chartjs-2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

```
 let GraphProjection = props => {
  let [chartData, setChartData] = useState({});

  let val1=props.recover[0]
  let date=props.recover[1]
//  let temp=length(date)
  //console.log('typ1 ', (temp));
 let jj=['323','3223']



  let chart = () => {
        setChartData({
          labels: date,
          datasets: [
            {
              label: props.recover[3],
              data: val1,
              backgroundColor: ["rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.6)"],
              borderWidth: 4
            }
          ]
        });}
     useEffect(() => {
    chart();
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{props.recover[2]}</h1>
      <div style={{height:"700px" ,width:"1200px"}}>
       <Line data={chartData} options={ {responsive :true}}/>

      </div>
    </div>
  )
```

### }

I am calling this component from other component

```
this.grapshow=( (<StatewiseGraphsec statecode ={this.x}/>))
```

For the first time it works but then it doesn't updates?? I think it is because of render issue.If I try to set state it's not allowing

Comment: What is exactly the value that you want to change to update your chart?

Comment: @PaulMiranda ....I have added you the response as a comment

Answer (score 0):

Actually date is constant Inam changing the Val1 which is the y-axis.
So I am having a dropndown in a component which I use to filter values and send to this component for graph creation.It works for first selection only.